# Sing me the song of days gone by, sing me the song that made me cry

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music, graph-theory

Sing me the song of days gone by,

sing me the song that made me cry.

The remorse, regret, and pain I'm in,

reflects the memories of what has been.

[image]

Hint 1

> Am                         C           D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This to me seems to be a pretty close fit to:

> the chord progressions used in the song [*Hurt*](https://www.e-chords.com/chords/johnny-cash/hurt-nine-inch-nails-cover), originally by [Nine Inch Nails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR4DjYczINM) but covered in this key by [Johnny Cash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AHCfZTRGiI) in 2002. The verse chords are Am-C-D and the chorus follows an Am-F-C-G pattern, both of which feature prominently in this diagram.
>
>   The music video for the Johnny Cash version has been widely acclaimed as one of the best of all time, and the song enjoyed another revival in 2017 when used in trailers for the Hugh Jackman film, [*Logan*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3315342/).

This particular song:

> contains a lot of lyrics about *remorse, regret and pain*, the first verse and chorus as follows:
>
>  *I hurt myself today*
>  *To see if I still feel*
>  *I focus on the pain*
>  *The only thing that's real*
>  *The needle tears a hole*
>  *The old familiar sting*
>  *Try to kill it all away*
>  *But I remember everything*
>
>  Chorus:
>  *What have I become*
>  *My sweetest friend?*
>  *Everyone I know*
>  *Goes away in the end*
>  *And you could have it all*
>  *My empire of dirt*
>  *I will let you down*
>  *I will make you hurt*